# Need help boxes attached to input fields using jQuery 

Tags: jquery, forms

Is there is any jQuery plugin or a script that attach a help div to an input field?

The help box only shows when the input field get focus.

Something like `http://www.morbuilding.com/docs/index.php?idConteudo=806`.

Comment: Where would the help text be coming from? Can you post some sample mark-up with which you'd like this plugin to work?

Answer (score 1):

You may to attach `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` and `focus` events to all input fields.

Test this: http://jsfiddle.net/q38wP/